# Unrolling list into function args?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, apply, splat, unroll

Given an argument list and a two-arity function:

```
args = [5, 6]
f = ((y,z)->y*z)
```

How do I unroll args into function arguments? - E.g. in Python you can do: `f(*args)`.

What I've tried (more JavaScript style I suppose):

```
Function.call.apply(f, args)
# When that failed, tried:
((y,z) -> y*z).call.apply(null, [5,6])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f(args...)`.

```
f = (x, y) -> x + y
list = [1, 2]
console.log(f(list...)) # -> 3
```

You can also mix and match this with regular arguments:

```
f = (a, b, c, d) -> a*b + c*d
list = [2, 3]
console.log(f(1, list..., 4)) # -> 1*2 + 3*4 == 14
```